# DataFrame Groupby gives all the values even after query

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(df_raw.query('COND1=="A" and COND2!="B"'))
df2=df1.groupby(['CAT1','CAT2']).size()
```

I've tried get row count after query data,
but after groupby, All the values are given with 0 value.

what I expected was

| CAT1 | CAT2 | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 2 |
| A | C | 5 |
| B | A | 7 |
| B | D | 3 |

but what I've got is

| CAT1 | CAT2 | COUNT | #COMMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | 0 | <- |
| A | B | 2 |  |
| A | C | 5 |  |
| A | D | 0 | <- |
| B | A | 7 |  |
| B | B | 0 | <- |
| B | B | 0 | <- |
| B | D | 3 |  |

These rows with arrow (<-) are given which were supposed to be deleted after query.

please help me how to get rid of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this after the groupby , is that what you're looking for?

```
df2.drop(df2.query('COUNT == 0').index)
```

RESULT:

```
    CAT1    CAT2  COUNT
1    A        B      2 
2    A        C      5 
4    B        A      7 
7    B        D      3
```